# containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier returns nil for a few users

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

I have an app in the store that uses the directory returned by `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:` for certain data. This works well and the app is live. I'm even throwing an exception in case this method returns nil.

Now I've got a couple of crash reports, stemming from my exception, meaning for a few users this method returns nil. According to *Crashlytics*, about ⅓ of these users have a jailbreak. I'm not sure if the other ⅔ also have a jailbreak but Crashlytics doesn't detect it or whether there may be **other reasons for this method to return nil**. Does anyone have a possible explanation?

Comment: Without seeing the full crash report or knowing more there's no telling...

Comment: The crash log is irrelevant since I'm throwing an exception myself if `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:` returns nil. Which it does for not even 10 of our ~50k unique users.

Comment: If you're worried about 0.012% of your users for an exception that you are causing *(6 total according to your question & comment)* then consider a different approach I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed up with Apple DTS and they think this shouldn't happen. So possibly an iOS bug, filed as [Radar 24882556](http://www.openradar.me/24882556).